# 4 - "$\pi$" / 4 approximates 4 * ("$\pi$" / 4)

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

I am not dealing with mathematics on a deep basis, but when trying to get $\pi$ from "Leibniz" series, I find that

4 - (series) approximates $\pi$ as well as 4 * series, under condition that there are not many terms present.

For example:

$$
4 - \left( 1 + \frac {1}{3} - \frac {1}{5} + \frac {1}{7} - \frac {1}{9}\right) \approx
4 * \left(1 + \frac {1}{3} - \frac {1}{5} + \frac {1}{7} - \frac {1}{9}\right)
$$
How would you describe/call this? I am asking for the name of the phenomenon.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This question is likely to be closed or downvoted since you don't provide nearly enough information to know what you're asking. If you edit your question to say explicitly what numerical phenomenon you would like the name for maybe we could help. Please use mathjax to write mathematics: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: But you haven't given a clear enough numerical example of the phenomenon.

Comment: Thanks, editing...

Comment: It's called "being close to $16/5=3.2$", because in that case $4-\frac x4$ is close to $x$.

Comment: What do the quote marks around $\pi$ denote?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I think you've understood the question. You could post this as an answer.

Comment: @Henning Makholm they denote, in my own terms, that PI is very approximate, i.e. not neccesarrily 3.14159...

Comment: @Ethan Bolker That's the thing about quotes, they denote that "x" is an alternating sum series with very limited number of terms. So is this a "valid" approximation, and is there a --name-- for it.

Comment: I think that the alternating series starts with a "minus" sign, should I correct it?

Comment: If you're asking for the name of "$"\pi"$ meaning an approximation to $\pi$" using the Liebniz series, you probably can't do better than the $\pi _n$ in the answer you accepted.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes. Noted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing too special. $\pi$ is rather close to $3.2=\frac{16}5$, which happens to be the solution of the equation $4-\frac x4=x$.

($4\times$)The partial sums of the Leibniz series calculate numbers $\pi_n$ which get closer and closer to $\pi\approx 3.1416$ as $n$ grows. Likewise, $u_n=4-\frac{\pi_n}4$ get closer and closer to $4-\frac{\pi}4\approx3.2146$.

Now, it's basically a matter of the first terms of $\pi_n$ being closed-but-not-too-closed to $\pi$, the first terms of $u_n$ being closed-but-not-too-closed to $4-\frac\pi4$, and $\pi$ being closed-but-not-too-closed to $4-\frac\pi4$. However, this proximity of estimates eventually disappears, as it ought to.

Comment: Could I argue that the 4 - $\frac {x}{4}$ $\approx$ x is $\mathbf {not}$ wrong?

Comment: Meaning, could we generalize this to $\mathcal y$ - $\frac {x_n}{y}$ $\approx$ $\mathcal x$?

Comment: Rather, 
$\mathcal {([x]+1)} - $ $\frac {x}{[x]+1}$ $\approx$ $\mathcal x$

Comment: For the first one, no. For the second one, it is generally true that, for $x\ge0$, and if $\{x\}:=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the fractionary part, $$\lfloor x\rfloor+1-\frac{x}{\lfloor x\rfloor+1}-x=-\{x\}+\frac{1-\{x\}}{\lfloor x\rfloor +1}$$ which is a real number $g(x)$ which satisfies $$-1<-\{x\}< g(x)\le -\{x\}+\frac1{x+1}\le 1$$